# Why is delete operation giving seg fault when I attempt to delete a non-existant value?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This is a helper program I wrote for a different homework assignment. - Full Disclosure - I do not have to turn this code in but I'm using a valid BST implementation to verify my in-order, pre-order and post-order traversals for homework. The traversals work fine but I get a completely unrelated error when I call remove(int) when the passed value is not present. When the passed value is present everything works great. My delete operation is comprised of three helper functions: remove, deleteNode and makeDeletion. I'd like to get this bst class fully functional. Thank you.

```
    // remove(int) is a private function called from main
    // when num exists in the BST there are no errors
    // when num does not exist in BST there is a seg fault

    void IntBST::remove(int num)
    {  deleteNode(num, root); }

    // deleteNode is a private function
    // that searches for the node containing num

    void IntBST::deleteNode(int num, Node *&p)
    {
      if (num < p->val)
        deleteNode(num, p->left);
      else if (num > p->val)
        deleteNode(num, p->right);
      else
        makeDeletion(p);
    }

    // makeDeletion resets the bst after deleting the passed node

    void IntBST::makeDeletion(Node *&p)
    {
      Node *temp = NULL;

      if (!p)
        cout << "\n Cannot delete empty node." << endl;

      // for nodes with one child
      else if (!p->right)
      {
        temp = p;
        p = p->left;
        delete temp;
      }
      else if (!p->left)
      {
        temp = p;
        p = p->right;
        delete temp;
      }

      // for nodes with two children
      else
      {
        temp = p->right;
        while (temp->left)
          temp = temp->left;
        temp->left = p->left;
        temp = p;
        p = p->right;
        delete temp;
      }
    }
```

Here is the error I found in my constructor, all of the above code that I posted works fine.

```
    // bad constructor
    IntBST()
    { root - NULL; }

    // good constructor
    IntBST()
    { root = NULL; }
```

Comment: *I'm using a valid BST implementation* -- Yet it faults when you give it a value that doesn't exist.  Doesn't sound too valid to me.

Comment: Use a debugger, or explain to your rubber duck what happens in `deleteNode` when the value doesn't exist.

Comment: Your `deleteNode()` doesn't check for `p->right` or `p->left` being `NULL`. Your debugger should have been able to tell you that.

Comment: Thank you I will check left and right for null here. ... I'm still a beginner and not very good with degubbers. I use putty and emacs but once I make the changes I will re-run with valgrind if I still get an error.

Comment: @Vic You should familiarize yourself with debuggers **as soon as possible**! They save tremendous amounts of time, while trying to debug your code (i.e. trying to figure out why your code doesn't do the thing you want it to do).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that temp holds the address of an object that is pointed by another object.

That is to say when you attempt to delete temp, the memory stored in the address of temp is referenced by the parent of p; which marks the memory location defined by the address stored in temp as reserved. So when you do: `delete temp;` you get a segfault since you are trying to delete reserved memory.

I would try setting the parent to point to null before attempting the deletion, see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In case that node p has 2 children,
after the while loop, temp->left is NULL, and you're trying to assign p->right to NULL which may cause a crash.

Btw, when you try to delete a node, you also have to change its parent's pointer, right ? Otherwise, you may break the structure of BST.